# Linq Query Optimization joining of tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

So I have a linq query, where `s1.code` comes from an object before this linq query.

```
var q1 = from cf in db.Control_Franchises
         join t1 in db.Territories 
             on     SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cf.FranchiseID).Trim() 
             equals t1.FranchiseID.Trim()
         join cu in db.Control_Users on t1.FK_CompanyID equals cu.PrimaryCompanyID
         join u in db.Users on cu.UserID.ToLower() equals u.Username.ToLower()
         where cf.Status == "ACTIVE" 
           && cf.FranchiseID > 1000 
           && cu.UserType == "Franchisee" 
           && cu.Status == "ACTIVE" 
           && t1.Province == s1.Code
         orderby cu.LastName ascending,  cf.FranchiseID ascending
         select new
         {
             FranchiseId = cf.FranchiseID,
             Province = cf.StateCode,
             DisplayName = cu.LastName + ", " + cu.FirstName, 
             UserId = u.PK_UserID
         };
```

I have the same block of code but this time in my where clause, I changed the filter from using `t1.Province == s1.Code` to `cf.StateCode == s1.Code`

```
var q1 = from cf in db.Control_Franchises
         join t1 in db.Territories 
             on     SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cf.FranchiseID).Trim() 
             equals t1.FranchiseID.Trim()
         join cu in db.Control_Users on t1.FK_CompanyID equals cu.PrimaryCompanyID
         join u in db.Users on cu.UserID.ToLower() equals u.Username.ToLower()
         where cf.Status == "ACTIVE" 
            && cf.FranchiseID > 1000 
            && cu.UserType == "Franchisee" 
            && cu.Status == "ACTIVE" 
            && cf.StateCode == s1.Code     // DIFFERENT FROM ABOVE
         orderby cu.LastName ascending,  cf.FranchiseID ascending
         select new
         {
             FranchiseId = cf.FranchiseID,
             Province = cf.StateCode,
             DisplayName = cu.LastName + ", " + cu.FirstName, 
             UserId = u.PK_UserID
         };
```

Now the first query runs 10 times as fast as the second one.
How I am measuring the speed though, is the load time of my Edit Page, which in turn is loading a mvc tree view of the nodes.  This query as well portions of a different query.

Now I'm trying to understand why my first query loads much faster and the only reasoning I can think of is because I am doing a condition on a table that will be joined, so rather then joining the entire "Territories" table with "Control_Franchises" I am only joining a portion of the "Territories" table.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two queries... Is there one that I am missing? They are even both named `q1`.

Comment: What types are `StateCode` and `Province`?  Both strings?  I'm guessing this is checking for U.S. vs. non-U.S. addresses or something...if so, is it possible the first query is running faster just because you have fewer non-U.S. entries?

Comment: Try using the [Mini Profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) to see the queries that are generated.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth in the `where`, the last `&&`d term is different. About to edit to make this not require hscrolling to see... @foop when posting code blocks, if you can, it's nice to re-flow text as required so that there isn't a horizontal scrollbar in the resulting code block.

Comment: @AakashM: Nice job finding that.

Comment: @AakashM thanks for the edit.  Will keep that in mind for future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the two different columns `t1.Province` and `cf.StateCode` are indexed differently  in underlying data source (or one isn't at all)

Comment: That was it.  *sigh* the joys of inheriting a legacy database with an existing system.